# Read from Azure DevOps Repo from App Registration

Tags: azure, entra-id, azure-devops

Is it possible to grant an azure app registration access to read from an azure devops git repository?  If so how?

Incidentally, Azure and Azure Devops have been linked via Active Directory, so they should be able to share credentials, but my App Registration will not show up when I try to add it to the Reader role in the DevOps Project.  I've also tried granting my app registration the API permission "Azure DevOps user_impersonation" (with admin consent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,  you cannot grant a service principal access to resources in Azure DevOps unfortunately. Using a PAT token is the only way.